# Boolean is FALSE when it should be TRUE

Tags: javascript, reactjs, boolean

I have a component that makes use of `node-horseman` to log-in in Google and manipulate the UI of Google Alerts, creating a RSS Feed. In my project I check if the user has `cookies.txt` file generated by the module, to check if it should log-in on Google or already be allowed to create a RSS Feed.

My component responsible for rendering the forms:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react'
import NewRSSForm from './NewRSSForm'
import LoginForm from './LoginForm'

class GoogleAlerts extends Component {
  render() {
    const {
      hasCookies,
      createRSSFeed,
      createRSSFeedSuccess,
      loginGoogle,
      loginGoogleSuccess
    } = this.props

    return (
      <div>
        {
          hasCookies
            ? <NewRSSForm
                createRSSFeed={createRSSFeed}
                createRSSFeedSuccess={createRSSFeedSuccess}
              />
            : <LoginForm
                loginGoogle={loginGoogle}
                loginGoogleSuccess={loginGoogleSuccess}
              />
        }
      </div>
    )
  }
}

GoogleAlerts.propTypes = {
  hasCookies: PropTypes.bool,
  createRSSFeed: PropTypes.func,
  createRSSFeedSuccess: PropTypes.bool,
  loginGoogle: PropTypes.func,
  loginGoogleSuccess: PropTypes.bool,
}

export default GoogleAlerts
```

Simple and easy. The endpoint checks for the existence of the file looking by the user `id`, which is the name of the folder the file is in, and returns either `true` or `false`.

```
* hasCookies() {
  return fs.existsSync(User.cookiesLocation(this.id))
}
```

The model `User` has a static method to return the default path for the location where the cookies shall be stored and read from:

```
static cookiesLocation(userID) {
  return `cookies/${userID}/cookies.txt`
}
```

By checking the returned value, I can clearly see it's correct, both for conditions where there is a file or not, but oddly, when it's `false` the component is showing the form that's suppose to be shown when it's `true`. I tested with `console.log` and it's also correct, but somehow it insists on showing the wrong results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the Redux. The following method is executed when the route is accessed:

```
export function checkForCookies(id) {
  return {
    [CALL_API]: {
      endpoint: `/api/linked-accounts/users/${id}/has-cookies`,
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      types: [ HAS_COOKIES, HAS_COOKIES_SUCCESS, HAS_COOKIES_FAIL ]
    }
  }
}

...

[HAS_COOKIES_SUCCESS]: (state, action) => ({
  ...state,
  checkingCookies: false,
  checkCookiesSuccess: true,
  hasCookies: action.payload.hasCookies
}),
```

The problem was in `hasCookies: action.payload.hasCookies`. I've forgotten to access `hasCookies` from `payload`, bringing the whole object:

`return ({hasCookies})`

Like that, it was returning it like this, and I was testing the Object, not its value:

```
hasCookies: {
  hasCookies: true/false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two isssues:

(1) You're not invoking that `hasCookies` function, so are not evaluating against its return value, rather it's type (of function which will evaluate to `true`)

(2)`hasCookies` is most likely being returned as a `string` 'false' or 'true' rather than a Boolean literal of `true` or `false`.

When javascript does a comparison with non boolean literals it will do a conversion from the data type into boolean type.

The following values are converted to false:

- null;
- NaN;
- 0;
- empty string (""); < -- this one applies to you here
- undefined.

So when you expect "false" to evaluate to `false` in a ternary expression, it actually resolves to true.

Solution:

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't see the mistake. `hasCookies` is suppose to be a `boolean`.

Comment: `hasCookies` is a function though?

Comment: That's the API. The Redux executes this function when accessing the route, then checks its returned value. I found out the issue, will answer it

Comment: Ah, I see. Cool :-)

Answer (score 0):

You aren't checking the *return value* of your `hasCookies` function, but rather the reference to that function (which is always true).

Check the simple example below:

```js
someFunction = function() {
  return false;
}

console.log(!!someFunction);    //returns true
console.log(!!someFunction());  //returns false
```

I'm doing the double negation (`!!`) because we're only interested in the boolean evaluation of `someFunction` and `someFunction()` because that's what the ternary expression looks for.

---

So change your code like so:

```
return (
  <div>
    {
      hasCookies()
        ? <NewRSSForm
            createRSSFeed={createRSSFeed}
            createRSSFeedSuccess={createRSSFeedSuccess}
          />
        : <LoginForm
            loginGoogle={loginGoogle}
            loginGoogleSuccess={loginGoogleSuccess}
          />
    }
  </div>
)
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't see the mistake. `hasCookies` is suppose to be a `boolean`.

Comment: @GabrielMFernandes, but you have a function called `hasCookies` also with `return fs.existsSync(User.cookiesLocation(this.id))`?

Comment: That's the API. The Redux executes this function when accessing the route, then checks its returned value. I found out the issue, will answer it.

Comment: What do you get if you do `console.log(hasCookies)` right before your `return()`?

Comment: The answer to my problem. It returns `hasCookies: { true/false }`. In the Redux, I was returning the whole Object and forgot to return the key of the object.